# how can I integrate airflow with pyroscope?

Tags: python, airflow

I want to use pyroscope with airflow in python tasks, do you have an example?

I tried to use the simple example but the python task wasn't processed.
it works fine with simple python pods.
im using ocp environment with python 3.10.